# getting error 3197 when deleting from MsAcces table linked to CACHE

Tags: database, ms-access, odbc

I have a MsAccess db (Microsoft® Access® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2201 Build 16.0.14827.20186) 64-bit ) that is linked with CACHE via an ODBC-driver.
It is installed on my harddrive, so no other users can be interrupting anything.

I have to delete records in a table.  I am doing this via a filtered recordset.

It worked fine, but now I get an error: "The Microsoft Access database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time."

- relinked the table
- refreshed the table
- reconfigured the ODBC-driver
- repaired and compacted the database
- imported all the tables into a new database
- in an older version same of the db (that worked) I now have the same issue
- delete query works
- delete via a recordset doesn't work
- delete manually, selecting the record and pushing the delete button doesn't work

Any ideas, I'm out of options ... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not quite sure about your specific problem here. Especially since you´re not able to delete it manually and a bit missing info, like

- is older version of the same db also run via ODBC
- is the aforementioned error occuring in both failed cases.

But I solved the multiple users access same data problem in most cases by checking my code with regard to the following:

- open recordsets that are not closed before the delete command.

  ```
  Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(stringSQL)
  ...
  rst.close
  set rst = nothing
  ```
- opened forms or subforms that need to be saved/closed before delete command
- use the right type of recordset([RecordsetTypeEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordsettypeenum-enumeration-dao))

surely that list is not complete, but that´s what I can think of atm.